# stdin → stdout?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

*What is the equivalent of the Unix `echo foo | cat`?*

`ECHO foo | TYPE CON` hangs, waiting for input, at least on Windows XP/SP3. Possibly `CON` is not stdin but keyboard input.

You may wonder what is the point of this exercise: There are programs which behave differently when they notice that their output is piped, and I want a way to test them.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `echo` isn't the same as **stdin**, and is already directed to **stdout** by definition, so the pipe to `cat` is redundant in this case.

Comment: @Dan Just updated the question with info about the *why*.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @foxidrive: Quote from [Node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console): *"The console functions are synchronous when the destination is a terminal or a file (to avoid lost messages in case of premature exit) and asynchronous when it's a pipe (to avoid blocking for long periods of time)."*

Comment: Dan's question - What are you trying to accomplish? will help define the actual problem, to see if there is a workaround for it.

Comment: @foxidrive As I write in my question, I want to test how applications behave when their output destination is a pipe.

Comment: @feklee In that case, `foo.exe | more` should work just fine on Windows.

Comment: @feklee How does the app know it's output is being piped? Does it check for _any_ redirection? If so, see my edit below.

Comment: @Dan Don't ask me how. But `Node.js` programs indeed differentiate between a file (`>`) and a pipe (`|`) as destination for output.

Answer (score 3):

Unsure what you want to do but this may help:

```
type file|more
```

And this may be more appropriate for your needs.

```
foo.exe | findstr "^"
```

Comment: `echo foo | more` would be the closest alias, but I'm still not sure what his goal is.

Comment: `MORE` is OK for me. It's not perfect though, since it pages, which I neither need nor want. Therefore I'll keep this question open for now, hoping for a better solution.

Comment: I like the findstr solution a lot!

Comment: +1, FINDSTR is the better option, as MORE will convert tabs into spaces. I believe MORE will eventually hang if the input is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you are looking for an application you can pipe to which simply passes anything piped to it through to stdout.

I believe `foo.exe | more` will serve your purpose on Windows.

Note: `more` does have the side effect of paging the output, so if you need to test longer outputs you could write a simple application which does the redirection.

Edit: You can write a simple batch file to redirect stdin to stdout and pipe to that.
From jeb's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979747/read-stdin-stream-in-a-batch-file):

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /n $') do (
  set "line=%%a"
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  set "line=!line:*:=!"
  echo(!line!
  endlocal
)
```

Save this as redir.bat and use like so `foo.exe | redir.bat`. Tested on Win7. Compatible with default Windows install. Only downside is it's not an easy one-liner to remember.

I would use `more` for simple cases, and fall back on this for longer outputs.

Comment: `foo.exe | tee` will provide an unpaged output - if he selects an appropriate third party tee filter

Comment: Indeed I have `tee` installed, from [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). I was hoping for something included in Windows. The programs I am testing (based on Node.js) detect `>` and `|` as different.

Comment: `foo.exe |repl "(.*)" "$1"` may work, where repl is a helper batch file called repl.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Comment: good plan.  The question was confusing so thought patterns were jumbled - you can just use `foo.exe | findstr "^"`