# Why is my piping failing?

Tags: windows, scripting, cmd, pipe

I've been messing around with .cmd scripts, and wanted to practice piping. I wrote one script to make files, and another to edit them with Notepad++. The making script (called create.cmd) is as follows:

```
@echo off
copy nul %1 > nul
echo %1
```

And the edit script (called edit.cmd) is as follows:

```
@echo off
start notepad++.exe %1
```

Now, I wanted to try and make a file, and then pipe its output (hence the echo line) in the form of the name of the file to the edit script. So what I wrote was this:

```
create foo.txt | edit
```

However, this fails - I get an open Notepad++ window, but my newly-created file does not appear there. What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading from the pipe in your second batch file.

For reading just one line of output from the first batch, the filename, this should suffice:

```
@echo off
set /p file=
start notepad.exe %file%
```

Otherwise check [Read stdin stream in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979747/read-stdin-stream-in-a-batch-file) for reading multi-lined input.

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved it perfectly. Out of interest, what does that /p do for the variable declared by set in your script?

Comment: The `/p` switch tells `set` to set a variable to a line read from the standard input. Type `help set` in the prompt, it is documented there.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I find a script with this solution no longer takes a normal argument! For example, if I try something like `edit foo.txt`, it asks for the input a second time! Is there any way I can default to a 'normal' argument if I'm not piping, and your solution if I am?

Comment: I suggest that you submit this as a new question. Nevertheless, on unix it is common to have the `-` argument indicate stdin. So you would say `tar foo.txt` or `tar -` and the tar command would know that in the second case it needs to read from the stdin instead of a file. You can check %1 and then decide to whether `set /p` or treat it as a file.

Answer (score 0):

edit.bat has no `%1` parameter

You could try this:

```
@echo off
copy nul %1 > nul
echo %1
call edit %1
```