# How can a batch file read piped input and write the result to a file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to write a Windows batch script `foo.cmd` such that when I pipe in any text to its standard input, it writes that text to a file called foo.txt.

```
echo hi | foo
```

The above command should create a file named foo.txt and write the text `hi` to it.

I tried this code in `foo.cmd`.

```
@echo off
copy con foo.txt
```

But this doesn't work. When I run `echo hi | foo`, the script simply waits for me to enter input via the terminal, i.e. Command Prompt window. It doesn't read the input piped it to.

How can I solve this problem?

Note that the text being piped may have multiple lines.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979747/read-stdin-stream-in-a-batch-file/6980605#6980605

Comment: As to why your code doesn't work, the `CON` device really does mean the console, not the standard input.  (There is no device name representing standard input, Windows doesn't work that way.)

Comment: @GuillaumeF. - That question requires a more complex solution than this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is a single simple FINDSTR command. The `"^"` search term is a regular expression that matches all lines of input.

```
@findstr "^" >foo.txt
```