# In windows batch files, how to split stdin around a keyword and pass half to another program?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, stdin, findstr

I have an executable, say, process.exe, that reads from stdin and outputs a processed version of it to stdout.  What I would like to create is a batch file wrapper that I can call in its place so that only part of the stdin gets processed.  Specifically, the part after a certain keyword is detected.

For example, let's say process.exe works by outputting the same lines that are given to it, just with a star added to the end.  (It is of course much much complicated, but just as an example.) So if I run it with the following input:

```
apple
banana
cantaloupe
date
```

I get

```
apple*
banana*
cantaloupe*
date*
```

What I want to do is create a batch file so that only the lines occurring after a line containing my special keyword are processed.  So, if the keyword is "keyword" and my input is:

```
apple
banana
keyword
cantaloupe
date
```

I want

```
apple
banana
keyword
cantaloupe*
date*
```

Note that lines before the keyword are still output to stdout, they are just not passed to process.exe.  How can I accomplish this?  Ideally, I would like to avoid writing to disk, since the input I will be supplying could be very large.  Now, I found out I can use `for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /n $') do (` in order to loop through stdin line by line, but it seems findstr consumes the entire input, so I can't pass any of it to process.exe...

If such a thing is impossible with Windows Batch Files, how about Powershell?

Comment: "*it seems findstr consumes the entire input, so I can't pass any of it to process.exe...*" - looks like it doesn't here -
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/6980605/478656 .   Yes it's very possible in powershell. `$words | foreach-object -begin { $KeywordSeen = $false } -process { if (-not $keywordSeen) { $_ } else { $_ | process.exe }; if ($_ -eq 'keyword') { $KeywordSeen = $true } }` or similar.

Comment: What have you tried so far, what part do you have problems with?

Comment: In PowerShell you could read the source in as a here-string, split on the keyword, pass the first part to stdout, split the second part on new lines, and pass those to process.exe. `$fileInput = (get-content $filepath -raw) -split $keyword; $fileInput[0]; $fileInput[1] -split '[\r\n]+'|Process.exe`

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "process="
(
for /f "delims=" %%a in (filename) do (
 if "%%a"=="keyword" set "process=Y"
 if defined process (process %%a) else (echo %%a)
)
)>outputfilename
goto :eof
```

Naturally, you could add `/i` to the keyword-detect if case-insensitivity is required, you could change `keyword` to `%~1` to input the keyword on the command-line. Switch the order of the `if`s if you want to **not** send `keyword` to `process`

And don't call the batch file `process.bat`.