# Pass a Python input parameter to a Batch File

Tags: python-3.x

Is it at all possible to build a Python GUI (lets say using `Tkinter`) and then pass the users input from the `Python GUI` into a windows batch file.
My objective is to make batch files have a nice front end using Python.

Simple example:

In the Python code the user will be asked for a date

```
date = inputInt("Please enter Date yyyymmdd")
```

Now I need to put this date value into a windows `batchfile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the the Python program you should use a [pipe](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), to redirect it's `stdout` to `stdin` of the batch file. In the batch file you can just wait on the `stdin` until something is outputed by the Python program. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979747/read-stdin-stream-in-a-batch-file) to see how to read an input stream in batch. It would look something like this:

```
python myprogram.py | batch_file.bat
```

Comment: There is a typo. Better to use pipes or you will overwrite the .bat script file: python myprogram.py | batch_file.bat

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to send the data to a text file

```
import sys

startdate = input("Please Enter StartDate YYYYMMDD ")
orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open('startdate.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = f
print(startdate)
sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()
```

I then used the following in my batch file to read the text file contents

```
@echo off
set /p startdate=<startdate.txt
echo %startdate%
```